# running multiple commands in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hello y'all am having problem writing the right code to automate the shutting down of 10 servers on my network, have cracked and thought and have tried every trick in book, so decided to bring it forth to the house for help.

first, am trying to make sure all the command executes in one window, i saw a code online on how to ping an IP address multiple times, i thought i could modify that to fit my need, its not just working

```
@echo off
start /wait cmd /c "@echo off&&for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (echo Iteration: %%i&&shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.2 & shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.3 & shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.3)"
```

Basically, i just want and automated script to shutdown multiple servers one after the other.

hope to read from someone soon.

regards

Comment: please expand on 'its not working'

Comment: as you write it, it seems, you want to shutdown them 10 times each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

    for %%a in (
        192.168.1.2
        192.168.1.3
        192.168.1.4
    ) do shutdown /s /m \\%%a
```

Comment: Anyway, i wanna thank the forum for coming to my aid, most especially @MC ND, your answer was the birth to the solution that finally worked. This is the code that worked '@echo off
start /wait cmd /c "@echo off&&for %%a in (192.168.1.1 192.168.1.3 192.168.1.2 ) do (shutdown /s /m \\%%a)"' This forum ROCKS!!! thanks again, cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to list the command in order? like so:

```
@echo off
call shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.2 
call shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.3
call shutdown /s /m \\192.168.1.3
```